# imagemagick convert command generating lots of images instead of just one

Tags: java, imagemagick, image-resizing

I am calling the following command from a Java app:

```
/usr/bin/convert "companies.png" -strip -quality 67 -density 92 -resize "300x>" -crop "300x300>" -format png result.png
```

But instead of getting one image back, cropped at 300x300 after being resized, I'm getting six slices of the same image, each 300px tall, which isn't exactly what I was expecting.

Any idea on how I could change this command to just get **one** image? This is a backend service, so having something that generates an unknown amount of images isn't really ideal.

The original image is available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOSJu.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with this:

```
/usr/bin/convert "companies.png" -strip -quality 67 -density 92 -resize "300x>" -crop "300x300>+0+0" -format png result.png
```

Comment: any idea why the +0+0 matters?

Comment: Awesome Leo! Gonna pay you a beer next time we meet :D

Comment: That's the offset of a given [geometry](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry). If you add a gravity, it changes where the image will be cropped. I can't explain exactly why this happens, I've been using this by heart for a long time! :D

Answer (score 1):

I see the same thing. However, ff I convert to a jpg first

```
convert companies.png companies.jpg
```

then run your command on the new jpg only one file comes out (jpg or png output behave the same with jpg input). It's odd that the input format seems to matter.

```
/usr/bin/convert "companies.jpg" -strip -quality 67 \
  -density 92 -resize "300x>" -crop "300x300>" \
  -format png result.png  #-> one file result.png
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add the option `-delete 1--1` to the argument list. This way you will delete the range of indexes from `1` (the first image of the sequence) to `-1` (the last image of the sequence). The result will be a single `result.png` file.

The command line will be something like this:

```
convert original.png -strip -quality 67 -density 92 -resize '300x>' -crop '300x300>' -format png -delete 1--1 result.png
```